# Kill child processes when parent windows service is killed via task manager

Tags: c#, windows-services

Firstly, I know that child processes can be killed when parent process (*not running as service*) is killed via Task Manager.

However, if parent process is running as windows service, the parent and child processes are not displayed in a tree structure in Task Manager. As a result, when parent service is killed, child processes still run.

Is there a way to kill child processes when parent service is killed via Task Manager?

I can't modify the code of child process. So I can't add code in it to periodically check the existence of parent's PID.

---

Minimal code to reproduce my issue:

```cs
// parent service
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .Build();

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "Test.ChildProcessApp.exe"
            };

            Process.Start(startInfo);
            host.Run();
        }
    }

// child process
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In OnStop() of parent service you can stop the child process

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(ChildName);
  try
  {
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
```